Unsupervised Sentiment Analysis in nlp
How to do sentiment analysis on unlabeled data, and I've looked all over the internet(gave clustering algorithms) and it was not effective. How to do sentiment analysis from scratch on unlabeled data , like using deep learning. I mean how do big companines do sentiment analysis like task with their data, do they label their millions of data
I've tried some clustering algorithms like LDA, Kmeans but they were not effective.
how to do it.
Or maybe point me to the resource for learning this
I've to do it from scratch and not use some pretrained model

I think you should post this as discussion in NLP collective. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/nlp/beta/discussions

With strong models you do not need large amounts of labeled data, a few hundred or thousand examples are enough (possibly even less). Approaches like LDA and clustering will not help you too much here since models do not know what constitutes "close together" or "far away" between documents, if you leave that to the model (e.g. by just looking at used words or n-grams) the result will be topic clusters rather than sentiment clusters.
There are many (large) datasets available online for sentiment classification, for example https://huggingface.co/datasets/sentiment140 with 1.6 million labeled tweets. If you search in Google, GitHub or Kaggle you will also find extensive lists of available sentiment analysis datasets.
What companies do is basically one of the following:

use existing fine-tuned models for sentiment analysis
use existing datasets to fine-tune their own models
annotate new datasets or combine new and existing datasets to fine-tune their own models

The choice depends on how specific your data is, if you have very specific language data or a very specific definition of what negative or positive sentiment means you might have to annotate data to get a decent performance.

Yeah exactly how are these datasets on the internet like the 1.6 million tweets, how did they label their dataset. I don't want to do it on the datasets available on the internet. You said about the strong models, what are those models, please tell
